# X.509 certificate with WCF service

Tags: wcf, security, encryption, x509

I have created a WCF service with X.509 certificate. I took a reference from this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36683/simple-steps-to-enable-X-certificates-on-WCF. Now it requires a certificate to be sent along with request to the server in order to access the service. My question is that does using a X.509 certificate in request encrypt the message to be sent to the server or do I have to do anything more to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A client sending a request to a WCF service should only require a public key to start off. If you have your service (and client) configured correctly, WCF should automatically handle the authentication / encryption before the transmission of your request content.

As I understand it, your client does not need a X509 cert.